# File Access takes me to command prompt rather than Explorer

Tags: windows, 64-bit, 32bit-64bit

Whenever I go to my command prompt and type a "c:\temp" or any other file/directory, it takes me to the command prompt rather than the file explorer. Can somebody please tell me how I can fix this so that all file/directory access from cmd takes me to the file explorer. 
       I have a Win2k3 64bit machine. Has this got anything to do with the 32bit/64bit explorer ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To run Windows Explorer from command prompt you must type name of the executable:

```
explorer.exe
```

or just

```
explorer
```

To open a certain folder, pass the path as an arguments. Details here:
[Command-Line  Switches for Windows Explorer (MSDN KB)](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/130510)
See examples.

Comment: Generally, this happens automatically.. All I have to do is go to the "Run" window and type "C:\Windows" and the Windows folder opens. But now it so happens that when I type "C:\Windows" on the "Run-Window(Win+R)" it opens the same thing on command prompt rather than the explorer :(

Answer (score 0):

To open Explorer at the directory where your cmd is operating you can use

```
start .
```

and at a parent directory you can use

```
start ..
```